# Can't use env variables in Jenkins Pipeline/Multi-Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins. Today I tried to create a Multibranche Pipeline.
I would like to tag the created docker image with the branch name.

My Jenkins file locks like follows:

```
node {
    def app

    stage('Clone repository') {
        /* Let's make sure we have the repository cloned to our workspace */

        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        /* This builds the actual image; synonymous to
         * docker build on the command line */

        app = docker.build("brosftw/minecraft")
    }

    stage('Test image') {

        app.inside {
            sh 'echo ${BUILD_BRANCHENAME}'
        }
    }

    stage('Push image') {
        /* Finally, we'll push the image with two tags:
         * First, the incremental build number from Jenkins
         * Second, the 'latest' tag.
         * Pushing multiple tags is cheap, as all the layers are reused. */

        /* Docker credentials from Jenkins ID for BrosFTW Repository */

         docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'e2fd9e87-21a4-4ee0-86d4-da0f7949a984') {
              /* If Branch is master tag it with the latest tag */
              if ("${env.BUILD_BRANCHENAME}" == "master") {
                   app.push("latest")
              } else {
                   /* If it is a normal branch tag it with the branch name */
                   app.push("${env.BUILD_BRANCHENAME}")
              }
         }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

docker push request from Jenkins job log:

```
+ docker tag brosftw/minecraft registry.hub.docker.com/brosftw/minecraft:null
[Pipeline] sh
[Minecraft-Test_master-ATFJUB2KKWARM4FFRXV2PEMHX6QFD24UQ5NGQXBIWT5YQJNXBAIA] Running shell script
+ docker push registry.hub.docker.com/brosftw/minecraft:null
The push refers to a repository [registry.hub.docker.com/brosftw/minecraft]
```

And the output of the echo command is the following:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Minecraft-Test_master-ATFJUB2KKWARM4FFRXV2PEMHX6QFD24UQ5NGQXBIWT5YQJNXBAIA] Running shell script
+ 
[Pipeline]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the env variables?

My second Issue is, that the `app.inside` doesn't return the branch name.... and I don't understand why.

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: What's actually your problem? What does _not_ work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the branch name using `env.BRANCH_NAME`. Further, you don't need interpolate variables inside strings.

So the last part should work as follows:

```java
     docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'e2fd9e87-21a4-4ee0-86d4-da0f7949a984') {
          /* If Branch is master tag it with the latest tag */
          if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
               app.push("latest")
          } else {
               /* If it is a normal branch tag it with the branch name */
               app.push(env.BRANCH_NAME)
          }
     }
```

Not sure, why you thought the variable is called `BUILD_BRANCHENAME`. It's `BRANCH_NAME`. You can see such list of global variables using the *Pipeline Syntax* link of a pipeline job (and then under *Global Variables Reference*).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for the answer! I didn't realised the wrong variable.